# FirstSpirit : Synchronization content source raises IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, database

When I try to sync my content sources, `FirstSpirit` is raising the exception:

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity xxx has no gid. Entities without gid are not supported.`

Anyone knows how to fix this to make the sync successfully?

Thanks a lot in advance.

> ```
> Admin (Admin), session: 5167312680662795708, project: 8385, ip: 169.254.30.75
> (de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor): [JC_Main]Handle failed [ActionEvent[AE@addElementsToSyncFolder,[<CONTENT2 editor="1" id="39967" name="brands" revision="10166" tabletemplate="103">
>           <LANG displayname="Brands" language="INTL"/>
>           <LANG displayname="Brands" language="DE"/>
>           <LANG displayname="Brands" language="EN-US"/>
>           <LANG displayname="Brands" language="ES-MX"/>
>           <CONTENTPARAMETER templateid="103"/>
> </CONTENT2>
> ]]@898975197]!
> FSVersion=5.2.212.71463#4747;JDK=1.8.0_101 64bit Oracle Corporation;OS=Windows 7 6.1 amd64;Date=07.10.2016 10:29:21
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity Brands [9] has no gid. Entities without gid are not supported.
>           at de.espirit.firstspirit.client.gui.navigation.ppool.sync.FileSystemSyncModelImpl.addEntities(FileSystemSyncModelImpl.java:374)
>           at de.espirit.firstspirit.client.gui.navigation.ppool.sync.FileSystemSyncModelImpl.add(FileSystemSyncModelImpl.java:216)
>           at de.espirit.firstspirit.client.gui.navigation.ppool.sync.FileSystemSyncModelImpl.add(FileSystemSyncModelImpl.java:179)
>           at de.espirit.firstspirit.client.gui.navigation.ppool.sync.FileSystemSyncHandler.handleAddElements(FileSystemSyncHandler.java:353)
>           at de.espirit.firstspirit.client.gui.navigation.ppool.sync.FileSystemSyncHandler.getHandle(FileSystemSyncHandler.java:259)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at de.espirit.common.gui.RunsInEDTProxyFactory$RunsInEDTInvocationHandler.invoke(RunsInEDTProxyFactory.java:143)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.getHandle(Unknown Source)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate.handle(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1099)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$AbstractActionProcess.handle(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1283)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$InnerActionProcess.handle(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1575)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$InnerActionProcess$1.onGrant(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1558)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate$1.handleGrantResult(AbstractActionProcessor.java:988)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate$1.onGrant(AbstractActionProcessor.java:970)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate$2.handleGrantResult(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1014)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate$2.onSuccess(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1010)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate$2.onSuccess(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1005)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate$3.onGrant(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1035)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate.grant(AbstractActionProcessor.java:956)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate.requestGrant(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1029)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$ActionProcessDelegate.grant(AbstractActionProcessor.java:993)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$AbstractActionProcess.grant(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1278)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$InnerActionProcess.grant(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1555)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$InnerActionProcess.start(AbstractActionProcessor.java:1550)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor.doProcess(AbstractActionProcessor.java:435)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor.access$600(AbstractActionProcessor.java:37)
>           at de.espirit.common.base.control.AbstractActionProcessor$2.execute(AbstractActionProcessor.java:588)
>           at de.espirit.common.util.ExecutorScheduler$ExecuteCommand.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:123)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Comment: without knowing what you did to get this error, neither what you tried to solve it, its difficult to help. But some people here are gurus... Show us the code, and read [ask] before asking your next question.

Comment: The exception message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities need a GID (which is technically a UUID) for transport. It seems you've got an older project where this is not the case. You can use the de.espirit.firstspirit.common.GidAgent to assign GIDs to these entities first. This must be done only once, new entities get a GID automatically.